# AFNetworking - Keep track on my Queries

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, afnetworking

How do I keep track of all my AFNetworking Queries between my UIViewControllers.

Do I have to make a NSOperationQueue on my AppDelegate file?

/ Morten

Comment: Better question, why do you want to keep track of a connection initiated by a different view controller? is that really global to your application? if it is, it belongs on a class referenced by the UIAppDelegate.

Comment: Ok, so the Best Way is to Call my Afnetworking request from my UIAppDelegate file?